# Angular - Ngx-mat-datetime-picker and TimeZone

Tags: angular, datetime

Im using angular datetimepicker https://h2qutc.github.io/angular-material-components/datetimepicker

In my application I have a switch to change the current Application TimeZone so every dates in site will be converted (from original UTC format).

For Example selecting **America/New_York**, every date will be printed like this: **2021-03-10 10:54:12 (-05:00)**

DateTimePicker starts with a default Adapter related to Browser TimeZone.

I need a way to set a specific TimeZone after the switch select.
I have the name and the UTC offset.